# MySQL Query Optimization LEFT JOIN and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, distinct

I have two table in MySQL :

```
system

Id_system   Name        Type
------------------------------
1           'System1'   'Type1'
2           'System2'   'Type1'
3           'System3'   'Type1'
4           'System4'   'Type2'

measures

Id_system   Sensor  Value   Insert_date
--------------------------------------------------
1           'S1'    12      '2019-23-04 15:16:05'
1           'S2'    2       '2019-23-04 15:16:05'
1           'S3'    42      '2019-23-04 15:16:05'
2           'S1'    11      '2019-23-04 15:11:05'
2           'S2'    3       '2019-23-04 15:11:05'
2           'S3'    43      '2019-23-04 15:11:05'
4           'S1'    2       '2019-23-04 15:10:05'
4           'S2'    32      '2019-23-04 15:10:05'
4           'S3'    2       '2019-23-04 15:10:05'
3           'S1'    32      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'
3           'S2'    54      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'
3           'S3'    15      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'
1           'S1'    10      '2019-23-04 15:00:05'
1           'S2'    1       '2019-23-04 15:00:05'
1           'S3'    35      '2019-23-04 15:00:05'
```

I would like have as result, the last measures for each systems, like this :

```
Id_system   Sensor  Value   Insert_date             Name        
---------------------------------------------------------------
1           'S1'    12      '2019-23-04 15:16:05'   'System1'
1           'S2'    2       '2019-23-04 15:16:05'   'System1'
1           'S3'    42      '2019-23-04 15:16:05'   'System1'
2           'S1'    11      '2019-23-04 15:11:05'   'System2'
2           'S2'    3       '2019-23-04 15:11:05'   'System2'
2           'S3'    43      '2019-23-04 15:11:05'   'System2'
3           'S1'    32      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'   'System3'
3           'S2'    54      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'   'System3'
3           'S3'    15      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'   'System3'
```

I tried this request in sql :

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.sensor, s.name, m.value, m.date_insert 
FROM system s 
LEFT JOIN measure m ON s.id_system = m.id_system 
WHERE s.type = 'Type1'
```

but she returns, each measures for each systems, while I just want the last measure of each type for each system :

```
Id_system   Sensor  Value   Insert_date             Name        
---------------------------------------------------------------
1           'S1'    12      '2019-23-04 15:16:05'   'System1'
1           'S2'    2       '2019-23-04 15:16:05'   'System1'
1           'S3'    42      '2019-23-04 15:16:05'   'System1'
2           'S1'    11      '2019-23-04 15:11:05'   'System2'
2           'S2'    3       '2019-23-04 15:11:05'   'System2'
2           'S3'    43      '2019-23-04 15:11:05'   'System2'
3           'S1'    32      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'   'System3'
3           'S2'    54      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'   'System3'
3           'S3'    15      '2019-23-04 15:06:05'   'System3'
1           'S1'    10      '2019-23-04 15:00:05'   'System1'
1           'S2'    1       '2019-23-04 15:00:05'   'System1'
1           'S3'    35      '2019-23-04 15:00:05'   'System1'
```

Do you have an idea of how to do it ?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: I use MySQL : 
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: and why `system4` is not part of your expected result?

Comment: Because `system4` is type of  `type2` and I want the element of `type1` in `system` table

Comment: The result i would like is last measures for each system which is type `type1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typical greatest per group problem

```
select m.id_system, m.sensor, m.value, m.insert_date, s.name, s.type
join measures m
join system s on m.id_system = s.id_system
from (
    select m.id_system, m.sensor, max(m.insert_date) max_insert_date
    from measures m
    join system s on m.id_system = s.id_system and s.type = 'Type1'
    group by m.id_system, m.sensor
) t on t.id_system = m.id_system and 
       t.sensor = m.sensor and
       t.max_insert_date = m.insert_date
where s.type = 'Type1'
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach works with some modification. I allow myself to comment the right query to obtain result. Thanks again.

Comment: `SELECT m.id_system, m.sensor, m.value, m.insert_date, s.name, s.type
FROM measure m 
JOIN system s ON m.id_system = s.id_system
JOIN ( 
        SELECT m.id_system, m.sensor, max(m.insert_date) as max_insert_date 
        FROM measure m 
        JOIN system s ON m.id_system = s.id_system
        AND s.type = 'GROWLIGHT' 
        GROUP BY m.id_system, m.id_capteur 
    ) t ON t.id_system = m.id_system 
    AND t.sensor = m.sensor 
    AND t.max_insert_date = m.insert_date
WHERE s.type = 'GROWLIGHT'`